SLD filter with "OR" combined "PropertyIsEqualTo" on a date field doesn't work
I have an SLD with a date filter.
The filter works, as long as I have only one field that I compare with ProperyIsEqualTo like this:
<ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
    <ogc:PropertyName>my_date_field</ogc:PropertyName>
    <ogc:Literal>2028-01-01T00:00:00+01:00</ogc:Literal>
</ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>

It also works with the Or and just one filter like this:
<ogc:Or>
    <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyName>my_date_field</ogc:PropertyName>
        <ogc:Literal>2028-01-01T00:00:00+01:00</ogc:Literal>
    </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
</ogc:Or>

It works with and combined PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo and PropertyIsLessThan like this:
<ogc:And>
    <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyName>my_date_field</ogc:PropertyName>
        <ogc:Literal>2028-01-01T00:00:00+01:00</ogc:Literal>
    </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
    <ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
        <ogc:PropertyName>my_date_field</ogc:PropertyName>
        <ogc:Literal>2034-01-01T00:00:00+01:00</ogc:Literal>
    </ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
</ogc:And>

However, it stops working, when I try to multiple or combined PropertyIsEqualTo with the date.
<ogc:Or>
    <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyName>my_date_field</ogc:PropertyName>
        <ogc:Literal>2028-01-01T00:00:00+01:00</ogc:Literal>
    </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
    <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyName>my_date_field</ogc:PropertyName>
        <ogc:Literal>2035-01-01T00:00:00+01:00</ogc:Literal>
    </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
</ogc:Or>

I also tried dateParse to get it work - but nope. Why does this happen?

What does the log file say?

I switched to verbose logging, however there are no logs. It generates the image, the style just doesn't apply. If I try any of the other filters, the style applies.

As a workaround we changed the PropertyName for one of the fields to a text property.
    <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyName>some_text_field</ogc:PropertyName>
        <ogc:Literal>2035-01-01T00:00:00+01:00</ogc:Literal>
    </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>

In this case it works again. So this issue only appears, if you have two filters on a date property.
